# Docker: Strider CD dashboard assets broken on installation

Tags: docker, boot2docker

### System

- OSX 10.9.5
- Docker version 1.4.1, build 5bc2ff8
- Image niallo/strider (latest) a51ba391459b

### Goal

Setup a docker instance as per [this guide](http://blog.frozenridge.co/docker-and-stridercd-brilliant-continuous-integration-in-a-box/)

### First attempt

I followed the guide steps, but when I ran the final image:

`docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -p 27000:27017 -p 44:22 niallo/strider`

I was not able to access the dashboard through localhost

### Second attempt: boot2docker ip

I did some googling and found these [OSX specific instructions](http://viget.com/extend/how-to-use-docker-on-os-x-the-missing-guide). Including the `boo2docker ip:`

`curl $(boot2docker ip 2> /dev/null):3000`

This succeeds in getting the dashboard html.

### Outstanding problem

However in the browser the html asset loads, but the front end assets `scripts/app.js` and `styles/style.css` are all broken links.

`curl $(boot2docker ip 2> /dev/null):3000/styles/styles.css`

*Note: all the other assets are fine*

Does anyone have any insight? I really wanna play with docker!

### More details

#### Info

```
bash-3.2$ docker info
Containers: 9
Images: 29
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Dirs: 47
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.16.7-tinycore64
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.4.1 (TCL 5.4); master : 86f7ec8 - Tue Dec 16 23:11:29 UTC 2014
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 1.961 GiB
Name: boot2docker
ID: DA3Y:GVFJ:6NO7:FFNL:RNLW:2QXY:UV3F:YWAS:OBFF:42YG:LRU7:CBHV
Debug mode (server): true
Debug mode (client): false
Fds: 18
Goroutines: 17
EventsListeners: 0
Init Path: /usr/local/bin/docker
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
```

#### Processes

```
IMAGE                   COMMAND                PORTS                                                               
niallo/strider:latest   "/usr/bin/supervisor   0.0.0.0:44->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27000->27017/tcp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the docker links in tutorial you have linked are broken. I can't even find the source dockerfile for this build and hence don't recommend using it and can't really help you debug.

However, The Strider github page recommends using [docker-strider](https://github.com/Strider-CD/docker-strider) image for running strider in docker. The instructions seem straight forward but you can ask another question on SO if you get stuck.